# DynamoDBDocument doesn't work when class implements interface

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I currently have a similar implementation and I am trying to save the table `TopLevelClass` with `DynamoDBMapper`

```
Public interface A {}

@DynamoDBDocument
Public class C1 implements A {
    variables…
}

@DynamoDBTable
Public class TopLevelClass {
    A obj;
    //Getter and setter of A 
}
```

I've tried without Interfaces and works fine, but once I add Interfaces this exception is thrown:

> com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException:
> not supported; requires @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted

I also tried to add the annotation to the Interface and the same exception is thrown.

I'm thinking if with a converter I can overcome this problem, but my table have 17 items that must implement a Interface, so i didn't want to go that way if DynamoDB has an annotation that "does the work for us".

Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own converter to do the same job as DynamoDbDocument.

Example:

```
@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = MyInterfaceConverter.class)
private List<MyInterface> myInterfaces;
```

Converter:

```
    public class MyInterfaceConverter
        implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<Map<String, AttributeValue>, List<MyInterface>> {

    private static ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public Map<String, AttributeValue> convert(List<MyInterface> myInterfaces) {

        final Map<String, AttributeValue> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < myInterfaces.size(); i++) {
            MyInterfaceImplementation myInterfaceImplementation =
                    (MyInterfaceImplementation) myInterfaces.get(i);
            try {
                String json = MAPPER.writeValueAsString(myInterfaceImplementation);
                Item item = Item.fromJSON(json);
                AttributeValue value = new AttributeValue();
                Map<String, AttributeValue> classToAttributeMap = ItemUtils.toAttributeValues(item);
                value.setM(classToAttributeMap.entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .filter(e -> e.getValue().isNULL() == null )
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)));

                map.put(Integer.toString(i + 1), value);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return map;
    }

    @Override 
    public List<MyInterface> unconvert(Map<String, AttributeValue> stringAttributeValueMap) {

    //                to be implemented.
        return null;
    }
}
```